# I have formset ignoring all attributes

Tags: python, django

forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(ModelForm):
    prefix = 'document'
    document = FileField(
        required=True,
        widget=FileInput(attrs={
            'accept': '.xls,.xlsx,.csv',
            'aria-label': 'File Upload',
            'class': 'form-control'
        })
    )
    header = IntegerField(
        required=True, label='헤더 행# (첫 행=0)',
        widget=NumberInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'min': 0,
            'value': 0
        })
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ['document', 'header']
        exclude = ['description', 'uploaded_at']


DocumentFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    Document,
    form=DocumentForm,
    fields='__all__',
    max_num=2,
    extra=1
)
```

views.py

```
def compare(request):
    file_paths, header_dict, step = [], [], 'start'
    header_dict, step = [], 'start'
    doc_forms = DocumentFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    ...(removed other code)...
    return render(request, 'compare/index.html', {'formset': doc_forms, 'user': request.user})
```

Note that I render as `{{ formset }}` and also the formset should only render 4 inputs.

[image: Resulting Screen]

I don't understand why the form is like so. Why is that happening even with extra and max_num set? Anyone can answer this I really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset):

> If you want to return a formset that doesn’t include any pre-existing instances of the model, you can specify an empty QuerySet:

```
DocumentFormSet(queryset=Document.objects.none())
```

If you do not specify the `queryset` then the formset will include all existing objects for the model

Comment: I have another question, what if I used a formset has no model?